# single server, windows box with sql server on same server, how to punch a hole to connect to sql?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I want to connect to sql server from my home computer to my servers sql server.

I know people say this is a security issue, but rackspace cloud sites seems to be allowing it? :)

Anyhow, how hard is it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the SQL Server version, but here goes:

- [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)
- In SQL Server 2008, you'll use the "SQL Server Network Configuration" portion of the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" tool to do much the same thing as in SQL Server 2005.

In both cases, you may need to [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the SQL server port opened through your office firewall. The SQL port is usually 1433.

At your office firewall they need to open the port, and forward it to the IP address of your SQL server.

In your SQL connection, you then use the IP address (or the FQDN if it has one) of your office internet connection.

As for how hard this is, this depends on whether or not you have access to the firewall yourself, or if you have to convince a sysadmin to do it!

If in any doubt, please see this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932).

Comment: actually, i'm referring to on the windows box at the ISP.   be default you can't access sql server remotely.

Comment: Oh, well that's something completely different, and is a question that's been covered dozens of times on ServerFault. I'll find a link to one...

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/58759/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-2005-to-accept-a-connection-to-a-private-or-interna

Answer (score 0):

If you open up a live chat from the link on their page ([clicky](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/)) I can pretty much guarantee someone will do their best to help you.  That's what they pride themselves on.